# Bounds for solutions of $x'=(A+B)x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t),B(t)$  be two matrix-valued functions, continuous in $[0,\infty)$, such that:

1) The ODE $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ has a fundamental matrix $\Phi(t)$ satisfying $|\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(s)|\leq M$ for all $0\leq s\leq t$, and

2) $B(t)$ satisfies $\int_{0}^{\infty}|B(t)|dt<\infty$.

Show that every solution of $x'(t)=(A(t)+B(t))x(t)$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @ChanG: Just want to confirm that you intend $\mathbf{X}'(t)=[\mathbf{A}(t)+\mathbf{B}(t)]\mathbf{X}(t)$ and not $\mathbf{X}'(t)=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{X}(t) +\mathbf{B}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to treat the original equation as if it were a nonhomogeneous linear equation
\begin{equation*}
x'(t) = A(t) x(t) + f(t)
\end{equation*}
with $f(t) = B(t) x(t)$.  Applying [variation of constants formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variation_of_constants) we obtain
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = \Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(0) x(0) + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(s) B(s) x(s) \, ds, \quad t \ge 0,
\end{equation*}
consequently
\begin{equation*}
\lvert x(t) \rvert \le M \,\lvert x(0) \rvert + \int\limits_{0}^{t} M \, \lvert B(s) \rvert \, \lvert x(s) \rvert \, ds, \quad t \ge 0.
\end{equation*}
Putting $u(t) = \lvert x(t) \rvert$, $\alpha(t) \equiv M \,\lvert x(0) \rvert$ and $\beta(t) = M \, \lvert B(s) \rvert$ in an [integral form of Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions) we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\lvert x(t) \rvert \le M \,\lvert x(0) \rvert \,\exp\!{\Bigl(M \int\limits_{0}^{t} \lvert B(s) \rvert \, ds\Bigr)} \le M \,\lvert x(0) \rvert \,\exp\!{\Bigl(M \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \lvert B(s) \rvert \, ds\Bigr)}
\end{equation*}
for all $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like that but never thought to treat B as the inhomogeneous part...